# how to use lambda function as a condition in ternary operator

Tags: php, lambda, ternary-operator

I'm writing a function which will be used to limit too long strings. I want to avoid duplicated code so I thought that putting almost whole function "logic" into return expression will be better than checking condition in every switch's case. But let's see code:

```
function test($mode, $string) {
    $x = strlen("...");
    $overThr = function($x, $y){strlen($string) >= $y + $x + 1;}; 

    switch ($mode) {
        case 'artist_week':
            $y = 29;
            break;
        case 'songs_week':
            $y = 31;
            break;
    }
    return (substr($string, 0, $overThr($x, $y) ? $y : strlen($string))) . ($overThr($x, $y) ? "..." : "");
}
```

as you can see I want to use $overThr as a flexible condition in a ternary operator. But I can't figure out why every time $overThr is executed in "return" expression it's always returns false.

```
$a = test('songs_week', 'razdwatrzyczterypiecszescsiedemrazdwatrzyczterypiecszescsiedem');
echo $a;
//razdwatrzyczterypiecszescsiedemrazdwatrzyczterypiecszescsiedem
```

does somebody know? :)

Comment: Off-topic, but for the sake of maintainability, you should really break down the return statement into multiple lines. (Sure you understand it at a glance *now*, but in six months...)

Comment: yeah, it's also nice hint. I guess it would also be helpful for those who answered this question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$string` is not defined within the closure and you forgot the `return` statement

```
function ($x, $y) use ($string) {
  return strlen($string) >= $y + $x + 1;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

You're using `$string` in the lambda, but not passing it in as a parameter or definining it as `global` within the lambda, so it's null/empty.

Comment: Please dont recommend `global`.